# Truncate text output of COPY command for postgres

Tags: postgresql, archive

I've got a script that copies every table in a schema to a csv using the following:

```
psql -Atc "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname='$schema'" --host=$host -w --user=$user $database |\

 while read TBL; do
    psql -c "COPY \"$schema\".\"$TBL\" TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER AS '|' CSV HEADER" --host=$host -w --user=$user $database > "${TBL}_${timestamp}.csv"
  done
```

Which by and large works great.  Now I've been asked if I can:

- Remove the milliseconds from the timestamp output
- Stop CLOBS from being moe than 6000 characters

Is there any way I can continue doing what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `COPY <table>`, you can use `COPY (SELECT <columns> FROM <table>)`, and work the truncation logic into the column list.

Of course, you'll need to build this list based on the type information in the catalog. This should do it:

```
  SELECT
    string_agg(
      quote_ident(column_name) ||
        CASE udt_name
          WHEN 'timestamp' THEN '::timestamp(0)'
          WHEN 'timestamptz' THEN '::timestamptz(0)'
          WHEN 'text' THEN '::varchar(6000)'
          ELSE ''
        END,
      ','
    )
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE
    table_schema = '$schema' AND
    table_name = '$TBL';
```

This query just generates the `<columns>` string to put into the `COPY` statement. Run it inside your `while` loop, put the output in a variable (e.g. `$columns`), and then run `psql -c "COPY (SELECT $columns FROM \"$schema\".\"$TBL\")...`